# Hide Highcharts export buton for mobile devices

Tags: highcharts

In highcharts charts how to display high charts export button only in desktop devices and hide export button for mobile devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the responsive options to hide the export button depends on the window width.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules.chartOptions